# Issue concerning loops

Tags: java

I have to make a program for school that asks the user to input the amount of items they want, and their respective price. After that  they have to input the GST, QST ( well taxes.) and the program has to calculate the subtotal and total.

I'm having a little issue. My program has to calculate how many errors the user "creates" by inputting wrong values. I hit a wall when I had to code the "ask for the price of each item". I tried a for loop, but eclipse terminates the program before it gets to the for loop ( for no apparent reason, so it must be a logic error, right?) Anyway here's where I'm at:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ItemCost {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        int items, d, item;
        double gst, qst, subt, Tot, PriceItems;
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input the amount of items bought");
        items = x.nextInt();

        while (items < 1 || items > 10) {
            System.out.print("Sorry the input was not correct, please try again\n");
            items = x.nextInt();
            i++;
        }

        for (item = 1; item == items; item++) {
            System.out.println("Please input the price of" + item);

            PriceItems = y.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is implementation specific and should be asked on StackOverflow.SE. One of the moderators will have to move it so that you don't get a duplicate question flag over there.

Comment: Ah my bad, still having trouble finding my way across this website. How do I flag a mod to move this question?

Comment: I already have done it, but the is a link that says flag under your post (closer to the comment link).

Answer (score 1):

Your `for loop` only executes when the user enters 1 as number of items because of this `item == items;` condition in your for loop. See the below corrected code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ItemCost {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int items, d, item;
        double gst, qst, subt, Tot, PriceItems;
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input the amount of items bought");
        items = x.nextInt();

        while(true){ //Changed here
           if(items < 1 || items > 10) {
               System.out.print("Enter items between 1 and 10(inclusive)\n");
               items = x.nextInt(); 
           }
           else {
               break;
           }
        }

        for (item = 1; item <= items; item++) { //changed here as well
            System.out.println("Please input the price of" + item);
            PriceItems = y.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Always initialize your variables before using them.

Comment: I see it, let me change.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for that help. I forgot to consider your case. I changed it now.

Comment: This is better now, but wouldn't OPs `while (items < 1 || items > 10)` make the code more readable? It shows directly what the loop condition is and when it exists it. But your loop works, as well.